# system.argumentexception on UIElement_TransformToVisual

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, panorama-control, argumentexception

Hy everyone,

I received a StackTraceData from Microsoft where I have a system.argumentexception:

```
Frame    Image                 Function                                                                Offset        
0        system_windows_ni     MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx                                         0x000000de    
1        system_windows_ni     MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack                                       0x00000218    
2        system_windows_ni     MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_TransformToVisual                      0x0000004c    
3        microsoft_phone_ni    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Panorama.ReleaseMouseCaptureAtGestureOrigin    0x00000064    
4        microsoft_phone_ni    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Panorama.OnManipulationCompleted               0x00000118    
5        system_windows_ni     MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler                        0x000003ae    
6        system_windows_ni     MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent                                        0x00000334
```

In my app I have a Panorama with 3 items, and in one of them I have a LongListSelector with almost 30 complex items(every item is animated, etc). I think it could be from long list selector but I'm not sure. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Thank,
Alex Manolache

Comment: Please share full details. Including the xaml will help to understand the issue.